# MVC + Autofac + MVC breaks when connection pooling activated

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, connection-pooling

My team and I have been developing this MVC application for about 3 years now, and all of the sudden we starting getting errors when communicating with the DB, and after some desperate search, and several users' discomfort, we were able to actually get it up and running by adding `Pooling=False` to the connection string for our EF `DbContext`.

I have been making some research and came across these links:

- [Tuning up ADO.net connection pooling on Asp.Net applications](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19395/Tuning-Up-ADONET-Connection-Pooling-in-ASPNET-Applications.htm)
- A few on Autofac and `IDisposable` behavior:

  - [Dependecy Injection and IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283564/dependency-injection-and-idisposable)
  - [Autofac and IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944369/autofac-and-idisposable-interface)
  - [Autofac Disposal methods](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html)
- [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

For my `DbContext` objects I have the Lifetime Scope set as `InstancePerRequest()` which, if I'm not wrong, means that once the request is served/finished then Autofac will call the `Dispose()` method on the `DbContext` and it should release the `SqlConnection` and ideally return it to the pool.

So my question is:

Should I do anything special to manually call `DbContext.Dispose()`?
Is there anything I'm missing how EF handles DB connections?

### Edit

This is part of my logs:

> "TypeName":"System.InvalidOperationException",
>    "Message":"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.",  "Source":"System.Data",
>   "Detail":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

that's the error I was getting when attempting to connect to the DB

Comment: What error(s) were you getting with pooling enabled? Also, do you know if anything changed in your SQL Server environment that might have caused the problem?

Comment: @JeffSiver I have just updated my question with the exception message I got. Hope that helps. Thank you

Comment: Unless something external changed (e.g. way more users, SQL Server changes limiting connections, etc.), I would review the code changes that happened before the problem occurred. My guess is that something in the code changed to cause the connections to be held onto longer than previously. Also, have you made sure this isn't the problem -
 http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#no-per-request-filter-dependencies-in-web-api.

Comment: There is quite a bit of info about how to deal with disposable per-request dependencies in the [docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html). Specifically, you should take a look at the tests and write some for your application that verify `Dispose()` is indeed being called with your particular setup. At the very least, you should be able to determine this by setting a breakpoint.